# How to use FlatDecode to PdfSharp library

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

I want to export some image from some PDF File, to do this I should to use a PdfSharp library.
I have find the code on the web to export image file from one PDF but if the image is codifing by DCTDecode I don't have any problems. If the image ise codifing by FlatDecode mode I'm not able to export this Image.

So this is the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    //estrapolare immagine da pdf
    const string filename = "d://eresult.pdf";

    PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename);

    int imageCount = 0;
    // Iterate pages
    foreach (PdfPage page in document.Pages)
    {
      // Get resources dictionary
      PdfDictionary resources = page.Elements.GetDictionary("/Resources");
      if (resources != null)
      {
        // Get external objects dictionary
        PdfDictionary xObjects = resources.Elements.GetDictionary("/XObject");
        if (xObjects != null)
        {
          ICollection<PdfItem> items = xObjects.Elements.Values;
          // Iterate references to external objects
          foreach (PdfItem item in items)
          {
        PdfReference reference = item as PdfReference;
        if (reference != null)
        {
          PdfDictionary xObject = reference.Value as PdfDictionary;
          // Is external object an image?
          if (xObject != null && xObject.Elements.GetString("/Subtype") == "/Image")
          {
            ExportImage(xObject, ref imageCount);
          }
        }
          }
        }
      }
}
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(imageCount + " images exported.", "Export Images");
}
    
static void ExportImage(PdfDictionary image, ref int count)
{
    string filter = image.Elements.GetName("/Filter");
    switch (filter)
    {
        case "/DCTDecode":
        ExportJpegImage(image, ref count);
        break;

        case "/FlateDecode":
        ExportAsPngImage(image, ref count);
        break;
    }
}
    
static void ExportJpegImage(PdfDictionary image, ref int count)
{
    // Fortunately JPEG has native support in PDF and exporting an image is just writing the stream to a file.
    byte[] stream = image.Stream.Value;
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(String.Format("Image{0}.jpeg", count++), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    bw.Write(stream);
    bw.Close();
}
    
static void ExportAsPngImage(PdfDictionary image, ref int count)
{
    int width = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Width);
    int height = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.Height);
    int bitsPerComponent = image.Elements.GetInteger(PdfImage.Keys.BitsPerComponent);

    PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode flate = new PdfSharp.Pdf.Filters.FlateDecode();
    byte[] decodedBytes = flate.Decode(image.Stream.Value);
    System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat;

    switch (bitsPerComponent)
    {
        case 1:
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed;
        break;
        case 8:
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
        break;
        case 24:
        pixelFormat = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
        break;
        default:
        throw new Exception("Unknown pixel format " + bitsPerComponent);
    }

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
    var bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, pixelFormat);
    int length = (int)Math.Ceiling(width * bitsPerComponent / 8.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * length;
        int scanOffset = i * bmpData.Stride;
        Marshal.Copy(decodedBytes, offset, new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + scanOffset), length);
    }
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\\" + String.Format("Image{0}.png", count++), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        bmp.Save(fs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
// TODO: You can put the code here that converts vom PDF internal image format to a Windows bitmap
// and use GDI+ to save it in PNG format.
// It is the work of a day or two for the most important formats. Take a look at the file
// PdfSharp.Pdf.Advanced/PdfImage.cs to see how we create the PDF image formats.
// We don't need that feature at the moment and therefore will not implement it.
// If you write the code for exporting images I would be pleased to publish it in a future release
// of PDFsharp.
}
```

With this code I can see the Image in this strange mode:

[image]

But the image in the Pdf file is this:

[image]

As you can see, the color is too different

Comment: Post a link to the PDF file so we can see how the image is embedded in the PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Image data and color palette are different objects in the PDF file. Images can have masks and these would be different objects, too.

When saving image data to a PNG file, you also may have to get the color palette and include the color data in the PNG file.

Maybe the code shown on the PDFsharp forum works better than your code:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=6755#p6755